# How to create a table of values with style for lateral limits study?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, grid-lines

I want to make a table to analyze a function when it tends to 1 on the left and on the right.
for example if this is the function

$\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}  \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}$

the table should look like this or similar, I found this example but with another function $x^2$

[image]

I cannot find any appropriate example in the forum to help the understanding of the question although I think it is understood.
help me in forming this format

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you meant or not.

```
 Grid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image]

code

```
f[x_] := (1 - Sqrt[x])/(1 - x)
values = {1.5, 1.9, 1.99, 1.999, 1.9999};
data1 = {#, Limit[f[x], x -> #, Direction -> "FromBelow"]} & /@ values;
title1 = {"From the left", SpanFromLeft};
title2 = {"x", Row[{"f(x)=", f[x]}]};
PrependTo[data1, title2];
PrependTo[data1, title1];
g1 = Grid[data1, Frame -> All];

data2 = {#, Limit[f[x], x -> #, Direction -> "FromAbove"]} & /@ values;
title1 = {"From the right", SpanFromLeft};
PrependTo[data2, title2];
PrependTo[data2, title1];
g2 = Grid[data2, Frame -> All];
```

Comment: @Naseer ,yes it is also useful for me, thank you very much

Comment: a question about how they fit next to each other, it doesn't look like that to me.

Comment: @rpujadas sorry, do not understand your question. If you are asking about the values, I used the ones you showed. You are free to modify the `values` to what you want. It does not affect the logic used.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := (1 - Sqrt[x])/(1 - x)

offsets = {0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001};

Grid[
 Join[{{"from the left", SpanFromLeft, "from the right", SpanFromLeft},
   {x, StringForm["f[x]\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", f[x]],
    x, StringForm["f[x]\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", f[x]]}},
  {1 - #, f[1 - #], 1 + #, f[1 + #]} & /@ offsets],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

```
lim = Limit[f[x], x -> 1]

(* 1/2 *)
```

Comment: thanks for the table as it is

Comment: can you explain to me how this last line works? {1 - #, f[1 - #], 1 + #, f[1 + #]} & /@ offsets],

Comment: See the documentation for `Function`, `Slot`, and `Map`. The pure function `{1 - #, f[1 - #], 1 + #, f[1 + #]} &` is mapped onto the values in `offsets`. This generates one row of the `Table` for each value in `offsets`. When you don't understand a symbol or operator, highlight it in Mathematica and press `F1` for help.